# How to parse pdf file using python

Tags: python, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python module for converting PDF to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text)
>   [working on tables in pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782972/working-on-tables-in-pdf-using-python)

I want to parse a pdf file in which there are number of tables.
I want to extract the table contents.

I have research but I did not find any suitable module to parse the pdf file for fetch the table content.

Can anyone help me in solving the same?