# Aspose converting only few pages of pdf to html Not All

Tags: java, pdf, aspose.pdf

I am using Aspose.Pdf for java to convert pdf to html. It is converting only first few pages of PDF to HTML but not all the pages. Is it a restriction only during free trial or am I doing something wrong. I ran the class com.aspose.pdf.examples.AsposePdfExamples.DocumentConversion.PDFToHTMLSingleHTMLWithAllResourcesEmbedded.java from the [examples](https://github.com/aspose-pdf/Aspose.Pdf-for-Java).

Code for that class is below:

```
package com.aspose.pdf.examples.AsposePdfExamples.DocumentConversion;

import com.aspose.pdf.Document;
import com.aspose.pdf.HtmlSaveOptions;
import com.aspose.pdf.LettersPositioningMethods;

public class PDFToHTMLSingleHTMLWithAllResourcesEmbedded {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Load source PDF file
        Document doc = new Document("input.pdf");
        // Instantiate HTML Save options object
        HtmlSaveOptions newOptions = new HtmlSaveOptions();
        // Enable option to embed all resources inside the HTML
        newOptions.PartsEmbeddingMode = HtmlSaveOptions.PartsEmbeddingModes.EmbedAllIntoHtml;
        // This is just optimization for IE and can be omitted
        newOptions.LettersPositioningMethod = LettersPositioningMethods.UseEmUnitsAndCompensationOfRoundingErrorsInCss;
        newOptions.RasterImagesSavingMode = HtmlSaveOptions.RasterImagesSavingModes.AsEmbeddedPartsOfPngPageBackground;
        newOptions.FontSavingMode = HtmlSaveOptions.FontSavingModes.SaveInAllFormats;
        // Output file path
        String outHtmlFile = "Single_output.html";
        // Save the output file
        doc.save(outHtmlFile, newOptions);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its confirmed from Aspose support that its a limitation during free trial only.
Sad :(

Comment: A 30 days [temporary license](http://www.aspose.com/corporate/purchase/temporary-license.aspx) can help to evaluate Aspose.Pdf without any limitation.