# vb.NET find words in PDF using Regular expressions

Tags: regex, vb.net, aspose.pdf

I am trying to find certain words in a pdf file using Aspose.pdf and regular expressions. The code is running without errors but never return TRUE.

```
Public Shared Function FindInPDF(sourcePdf As String, searchPhrase As String) As Boolean

        Try
            ' Open document
            Dim pdfDocument = New Document(sourcePdf)

            '   "D[a-z]{7}"
            ' Create TextAbsorber object to find all the phrases matching the regular expression
            Dim absorber As Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragmentAbsorber = New Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragmentAbsorber(searchPhrase) With {
                .TextSearchOptions = New TextSearchOptions(True)
            }

            ' Accept the absorber for all the pages
            pdfDocument.Pages.Accept(absorber)

            ' Loop through the fragments
            For Each textFragment As Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragment In absorber.TextFragments
                Console.WriteLine("Text : {0} ", textFragment.Text)
                FindInPDF = True
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return FindInPDF
    End Function
```

Is there an error in my code?

The regular expressions string is inserted in the function through `searchPhrase`

Comment: This code works for me, returns `true` when It finds my text. What is your `searchPhrase`?

Comment: ...oh wait, if your searchPhrase is farther down the .PDF, like near the bottom, it does not find it. Hmmm.

Comment: @NickAbbot Maybe my regex is wrong Library[a-z]{7}

Comment: It seems to be a [limitation of the free trial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959801/aspose-converting-only-few-pages-of-pdf-to-html-not-all).

Comment: @NickAbbot Is there nothing out there without limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Aspose.pdf`, which is a paid library, I switched to `iTextSharp`. It has the same functionality.

```
Public Shared Function GetTextFromPDF2(ByVal PdfFileName As String, searchPhrase As String) As Boolean

        Try
            Dim oReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PdfFileName)
            Dim sOut = ""
            For i = 1 To oReader.NumberOfPages
                Dim its As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy
                sOut &= iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, i, its)
                Dim adrRx As Regex = New Regex(searchPhrase)
                Dim keyword As New List(Of String)
                For Each item As Match In adrRx.Matches(sOut.ToLower)
                    keyword.Add(item.Value)
                    GetTextFromPDF2 = True
                Next

            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return GetTextFromPDF2
    End Function
```